# How can I include the original filename when Sprockets combines javascript files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

We are using the latest version of Sprockets on Rails 3.0.10. Everything is working great, and overall it's been a smooth and problem free deployment, but we do have one minor annoyance that I hope there is a simple solution for.

When javascript files are combined together, there's no simple, straightforward way to determine what file a particular bit of javascript came from when I'm debugging in a browser.

We use SASS as well and I love the way that it includes comments indicating where the rule can be found in my original CSS file.

Are there options or flags I can set on Sprockets to allow similar behaviour? (say, an auto-generate comment at the beginning of each included file indicating it's original path)

Answer (score 1):

In case you can't solve your problem, you could try using Rails 3.1 : the asset pipeline isn't compiled in the development environment, so you can immediately see in which javascript file your problem is.

Comment: Good to know. We've tried a rails 3.1 upgrade but a few of our gem dependencies still need some work.

Comment: I've also recently upgraded one of my apps from Rails 3 to 3.1. I suggest you keep referring to your old Gemfile to have a baseline of working and compatible gem versions, then go from there...